# Crossover Anaylsis

Tags: qgis

I have a text file with (lat,long) of flight lines. If I view the coordinates, they are points, but I am interested in drawing the path of those points, basically connecting them and determining the intersection (crossover) of flight lines (lat, lon).

Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

My example data are:

LAT LONG -75.30355274   -87.96741337 -75.30356028 -87.96784233 -75.30356792 -87.96827128 -75.3035835    -87.969129 -75.30359144 -87.96955776 -75.30359949   -87.96998605 -75.30363279   -87.97170026 -75.30365013   -87.97255694 -75.30365897 -87.97298515 -75.30366793 -87.97341337 -75.30368619   -87.97426955 -75.3036955    -87.97469747 -75.3037241    -87.97598105 -75.30374375   -87.9768363 -75.30376383    -87.9776909 -75.30380538 -87.97940021 -75.30382682  -87.98025446 -75.30383771   -87.98068147 -75.3038487    -87.98110837 -75.30385982   -87.98153525 -75.30387106   -87.98196204

Comment: Do you have any python ability? I create flight line shapefiles for LiDAR using python, however I use ESRI objects and create vertices by reading the text file and finish the line at EOF. No doubt you could do similar with OGR objects and python is the platform I would choose: quick to write, easy to modify for a different but similar task and can use GDAL/OGR.

Comment: Can you post a couple of rows from your data? I had done something similar a few months back, and depending on your data, I could help you out.

Comment: Thanks @ Devdatta! My example data are:
LAT LONG
-75.30355274 -87.96741337
-75.30356028 -87.96784233
-75.30356792 -87.96827128
-75.3035835 -87.969129
-75.30359144 -87.96955776
-75.30359949 -87.96998605
-75.30363279 -87.97170026
-75.30365013 -87.97255694
-75.30365897 -87.97298515
-75.30366793 -87.97341337
-75.30368619 -87.97426955
-75.3036955 -87.97469747
-75.3037241 -87.97598105
-75.30374375 -87.9768363
-75.30376383 -87.9776909
-75.30380538 -87.97940021
-75.30382682 -87.98025446
-75.30383771 -87.98068147
-75.3038487 -87.98110837
-75.30385982 -87.98153525
-75.30387106 -87.98196204

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin Points to Paths / Points to One. You will be wanting each of the unique flight lines to have an index or common value which identifies the points as belonging to a particular path.